# Binary Goppa Codes: Calculating code characteristics (traces, length L, distance d, k)

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

I am having (many) troubles with binary Goppa Codes. My question is at the moment: How do I calculate the trace on given points $tr(\alpha^u)$?
For example: Given a finite field $GF(2^6)$ and the Goppa Polynomial

$G(z)= (z^2 + z + \alpha^{32}) * (z^2 + z + \alpha^{33}$)

and knowing that the cyclotomic cosets for $c_1$ and $c_3$ are

$c_1 = \{1,2,4,8,16,32\}$ and $c_2 = \{3,6,12,24,48,33\}$

how do I calculate $tr(\alpha^{32})$ and $tr(\alpha^{33})$?

How can I determine the *code size* $n = |L|$ and the parameters *distance* $d$ and the *amount of information bits* $k$?

**UPDATE:** The irreducible polynomial of the given finite field is $p(x) = x^6 + x^5 + x^3 + x^2 +1$. $\alpha$ is supposed to be the zero of $p(x)$ and is itself an element of the finite field, ideally a primitive element.

Comment: The answers depend on what you mean by $\alpha$. Is it a primitive element of $GF(64)$ with a known minimal polynomial or what?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I added some more details. Hope it helps to clarify the question.